# How do I make a bulleted list in spoiler tags?

Tags: support, editing

I want a bulleted list in spoiler tags. I tried just doing >! *, but that ends up with the below

> *spoiler bullet 1
>  *spoiler bullet 2

Answer (score 6):

Use actual HTML.

> - Item One
> - Item Two

```
>! <ul><li> Item One</li>
>! <li> Item Two</li></ul>
```

Though, please consider that we have pretty open policies for spoilers here, outside of question titles, so be sure you're not putting your entire question or answer in spoiler markup.